# Hide top and bottom menus from Midnight Commander

Tags: mc

Can I hide top ("File", "Options", etc) and bottom ("Help", "View", "Edit", etc) menus from Midnight Commander? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to **Option->Layout** you'll see various boxes you can tick and untick as visible.  "Menubar" is the top part you are referring to, and "Keybar" is the bottom.  Both of these can be hidden.

To show the Menubar temporarily once it's hidden, press **F9**.

Plenty of other options and shortcuts are detailed in the manual page `man mc`, and in the Help (**F1**) section *Keys*.